List all images for a set of tags from all repos in a container registry
There are several repos in my Azure Container Registry. Related images in different repos will have the same tag. Using PowerShell, I want a list of all images for a given tag, from all repos in the container registry. After getting that, I can figure out how to get a list of images, from all repos, for a given set of tags.

It took some research. The PowerShell book and the Az.ContainerRegistry command reference were helpful.
The code below will accomplish the goal, although "NotFound" error messages clutter the output a bit.
Connect-AzAccount

$registry = "YOUR_REGISTRY_NAME"
$repos = Get-AzContainerRegistryRepository -RegistryName $registry
$tags = "b926b3c", "v3.6.0", "v1.1.0", "v0.27.0"
$images = New-Object 'object[,]' 0,1

foreach ($repo in $repos) { 
    Update-AzContainerRegistryRepository -RegistryName $registry -Name $repo -ReadEnable $true -ListEnable $true
}

foreach ($repo in $repos) 
{ 
    foreach ($tag in $tags)
    {   
        $img = Get-AzContainerRegistryTag -RegistryName $registry -RepositoryName $repo -Name $tag
        Write-Output $img
        if ($img) {
            Write-Output "Adding to list:" $img
            $images += $img
        }
    }
}
Write-Output $images

I can check the attributes of an image with something like the following:
PS /Users/denu> $images[0].Attributes

Name                 : v3.6.0
Digest               : sha256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
CreatedTime          : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.00000000
LastUpdateTime       : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.00000000
Signed               : False
ChangeableAttributes : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ContainerRegistry.Models.PSChangeableAttribute

